# structs - why gets function is not working compared to scanf?

Tags: c

gets(edu.classes[i].students[j].name);

I would like to know why the compiler skips this line after debugging and does not input into name? Is it legal to invoke gets function on that way?

Note: Once I use scanf("%s" , ... ) - it works!

scanf("%s",edu.classes[i].students[j].name);

(I know that I did not free the memory allocations and checked if the allocations were not failed  - I know that it is necessary! It's only time issue) :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 20

typedef struct
{
char name[SIZE];
int id;
}Student;

typedef struct
{
Student *students;
int num_students;
char teacher[SIZE];
}Class;

typedef struct
{
Class *classes;
int num_classes;
}Education;

int main()
{
int i, j;
Education edu;
puts("how many classes?");
scanf("%d", &(edu.num_classes));
edu.classes = (Class*)malloc((edu.num_classes) * sizeof(Class));
if (edu.classes == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR allocation\n");
    exit(1);
}
for (i = 0; i < edu.num_classes; i++)
{
    puts("enter num of students");
    scanf("%d", &(edu.classes[i].num_students));
    edu.classes[i].students = (Student*)malloc((edu.classes[i].num_students) 
* sizeof(Student));
    for (j = 0; j < edu.classes[i].num_students; j++)
    {
        puts("enter student's name");
        gets(edu.classes[i].students[j].name); // this is the problematic line
        puts("enter id");
        scanf("%d", &(edu.classes[i].students[j].id));
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: _never_ use `gets`.

Comment: I would recommend to use `fgets` instead of `gets`, its error-prone

Comment: that said, I don't know why this wouldn't work. Use `scanf("%19s" ...)` to protect against buffer overflow

Comment: The obsolete `gets` consumes *only* the newline left in the input buffer after the previous `scanf`. Don't mix your methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is seeing the newline character that was produced due to hitting the enter key. `gets` then stops reading. Try eating those special characters before `gets` sees them. Or use scanf with `%s` which eats any leading whitespace as you have seen it works.

Comment: do you mean by fflush?

Comment: Actually I meant reading characters from the standard input until it is no longer a special character like newline (\n).

Comment: well... you gave me an idea :)
I just write this command line twice.

Comment: this is my "solution" :
   gets(edu.classes[i].students[j].name);
   gets(edu.classes[i].students[j].name);

Comment: But scanf with %s also skips the leading whitespace. Besides `scanf` can be told not to read more than a certain amount of characters while `gets` can crash your program.

Comment: I have already tried scanf with %s and it worked well